# String diamond pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to make a diamond text pattern using Python, but I am a little stuck on how to get the shape like I want.

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length):
    for j in range(length-i-1):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()
for l in range (1,length):
    for j in range(l) :
        print(' ', end="")
    for m in range (0,length-l-1):
        print(word[m], end ="")
    print()
```

This code output for "project" string

```
        p                                                                                                  
       p r                                                                                                 
      p r o                                                                                                
     p r o j                                                                                               
    p r o j e                                                                                              
   p r o j e c                                                                                             
  p r o j e c t                                                                                            
    p r o j e c                                                                                            
      p r o j e                                                                                            
        p r o j                                                                                            
          p r o                                                                                            
            p r                                                                                            
              p
```

but I want output like:

```
   p
  pro
 proje
project
 proje
  pro
   p
```

Comment: Why do you have this loop: `for k in range (i-1, -1, -1):`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist to print the word in reverse ?

Comment: @lenik. I understand what it does. I don't understand why OP included it while specifically saying they don't want that behavior.

Comment: @MadPhysicist he's got the code (listed above), now he wants to modify it.

Comment: @lenik. If he added that in by accident, I've just pointed out his problem. If he grabbed code from somewhere without taking the time to understand it, I don't want to help. Either way, I want to know why that snippet is there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it

```
word = "project"
index = 1
di = 2
for line in range(len(word)):
    if index == len(word):
        di *= -1
    space = " " * (len(word) - index//2)
    print(space + word[0:index])
    index += di
```

output:

```
   p
  pro
 proje
project
 proje
  pro
   p
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified you code hope this helps.

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length,2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()

for i in range (length - 3,-1,-2):
    for j in range(length-i//2):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    print()
```